# Arrange table row in the basis of table data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have the code like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</td>
        <th>price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td class="sort">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but it should be arranged this way:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</td>
        <th>price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td class="sort">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Arranging the table data in basis of table data.
note: the class will be defined `class="sort"`

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I want the table to be arranged without any click of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By converting rows to an array using `$.makeArray` you can use natve javascript `sort()` on the array. I sorted numerical since it seemed applicable

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3MBPF/

```
function sortNum(a, b) {
   return 1 * $(a).find('.sort').text() < 1 * $(b).find('.sort').text() ? 0 : 1;
}

$(function() {
    var elems = $.makeArray($('tr:has(.sort)').remove())
    elems.sort(sortNum)
    $('table').append($(elems));
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me in something more?

Sort the table row only if the text inside the table data is integer or float..

????

Comment: here's some sort functions that will help  http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1671288

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like you haven't tried anything due to a lack of code and you haven't told us how you are generating the pages / table (the question seems to ask us to do the work for you rather than help) but take a look at this: http://datatables.net/ it may give you the solution you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Tinysort plugin available at http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/. That should cover most of your sorting needs.